# Angular get the $event from template selector

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" #myFile multiple />
<button (click)="onDelete(myFile.event)">DeleteFiles</button>
```

In the above `myFile.event` returning undefined! how to get the `myFile` $event through a button click, *I have required to delete only one file from user selection*.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<button (click)="onDelete($event)">DeleteFiles</button>
```

Comment: required input event, not button event

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you actually need any `$event`. I think you are instead looking for something like this:

```html
<input type="file" #myFile multiple>
<button (click)="onDelete(myFile.files)">DeleteFiles</button>
```

or:

```html
<input type="file" #myFile multiple>
<button (click)="onDelete(myFile.value)">DeleteFiles</button>
```

Comment: But required to modify files through onDelete, not possible through results like [myFile.files], won't reflect.

Comment: @Selvakumar I do not believe what you are asking for is possible. You cannot remove an individual file from a multiple-file input, you can only clear out all the files. You would need to make your own custom multiple-file input control or use a third-party one.